# Can I update the delve profile image for SharePoint Online programatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, user-profile, my-site

Can I update the profile picture of SharePoint Online users programmatically?

I want to update profile pic so that the profile pic converted into 3 different resolution and uploaded into **`/User Photos/Profile Pictures/`** library of host Mysite site collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the PowerShell script which will update the profile picture of Delve user in SharePoint Online from [here](http://tszulczewski.com/user-photo-in-office-365-how-to-solve-problems/).

The script is:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/?proxyMethod=RPS -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$user1 = ([Byte[]] $(Get-Content -Path C:\1\Tomek1.jpg -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0))
set-userphoto -identity user@domain.anme -picturedata $user1
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Comment: Great answer :) , can you accept it as well so that it won't show up in the unanswered section ? Thanks :)